# Prove an equation is solvable/unsolvable

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Prove the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is unsolvable by square roots but it's solvable by cube roots

Comment: i thought that might be (x + 1 / 2)^2 + 3/4 = 0 and  (x + 1 / 2)^2 = -3/4  is that solvable with square roots over Z or am I out of my depth?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, you've solved the equation on $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Note that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: What Mathmo123 says. Also observe that every element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is its own square root, and you get all their square roots in this way (its a doubled root because sign makes no difference here). But $1$ has cube roots $\neq1$ in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_4$ (and these are the solutions).